# Simple javascript function doesn't work when placed outside of tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that changes a paragraph's content:

```
function test() {      
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ops2"
}
```

When used inside a tag it works fine:

```
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ops"'>Change Content</button>
```

However when placed outside in a function it doesn't work:

```
<button type="button" onclick=test()>load</button>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw7atzey/). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your fiddle is not using the function

Comment: ... and if it was you'd need to change 'Load type' in the JS settings to `No wrap - in <head>`

Comment: I think you may have linked to the wrong fiddle? The code as given in the question itself works just fine.  (It would probably be a good idea to enclose the onclick in quotes: `onclick="test()"`, but it does work correctly even without them.)

Comment: I would write the function name in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Its just matter of sequence of script and html code. When I put `test` function on top of html code, and then called the function with `onclick="test()"` it worked well.

So here is what I did: **(Notice the `Change Content` button tag.)**

```
<script>
    function test(){
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ops2"
    }
</script>

<h3 id="demo">Hello</h3>
<p>Here is some text</p>
<center>
  <img id="lamp" src="https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif"/>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <button type="button" onClick='test()'>Change Content</button>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <button type="button" onClick='document.getElementById("lamp").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif"'>Light</button>
    <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("lamp").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif"'>Dark</button>
  <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("lamp").src = ""'>Hide</button>
  <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("lamp").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif"'>Show</button>
</center>
```

Comment: The order of the scripts doesn't matter when the function is called in the onclick handler. Everything has loaded by the time the user clicks the button.

Comment: But the way I suggested made it working, and the JSFIDDLE was giving error that `test` is not defined.

Comment: Yes, and that's because jsfiddle places the JS code inside a window.onload event handler which takes the function out of global scope. Nothing to do with script order. Your code will work just as well if you place the function at the end of the page.